# Upgrading to the latest jquery library broken my functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried to upgrade the jquery library from 1.11.2 `(<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>)` to 2.1.0 `(<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>)` and as I did that, my jquery functions simply stopped running on-load and only on re-size.

Why is that? is the (window).ready outdated now? Please can someone point out what I need to change/update?

Here are three of the functions:

```
    //Fullscreen
    $(window).on("ready resize", function() {
        if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            var newHeight = $("html").height() + "px";
            $(".fullscreen").css("height", newHeight);
        } else {
            var newHeight = $("html").height() + "px";
            $(".fullscreen").css("height", newHeight);
        }
    });

    //Header & page stubilizer
    $(window).on("ready resize", function() {
        if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
            if (!$('#header').hasClass("header-fixed")) {
                var pageTop = $("#header").outerHeight() + "px";
                $("#page .topSection").css({
                    "padding-top" : pageTop,
                    "margin-top" : "-" + pageTop
                });
            }
            if ($('#header').hasClass("header-fixed")) {
                var pageTop = $("#header").outerHeight() + "px";
                $("#page .topSection").css({
                    "padding-top" : pageTop,
                    "margin-top" : 0
                });
            }
        } else {
            var pageTop = $("#secondHeader").outerHeight() + "px";
            $("#page .topSection").css({
                "padding-top" : pageTop,
                "margin-top" : 0
            });
        }
    });

//Off-Canvas Menu
    $(function offCanvasMenu() {
        var $page = $('#page, #header'), 
        $mainMenu = $('#mainMenu'), 
        $menuSwitch = $('#header').find('.mainMenu-switch'),
        $menuSwitchIcon = $('#header').find('.mainMenu-switch-icon');

        $menuSwitch.on('touchstart click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $page.toggleClass("pageOpen");
            $mainMenu.toggleClass("mainMenuOpen");
            $menuSwitchIcon.toggleClass("mainMenu-switch-active");
        });
        $('#page').on('touchstart click', function() {
            $page.removeClass("pageOpen");
            $mainMenu.removeClass('mainMenuOpen');
            $menuSwitchIcon.removeClass("mainMenu-switch-active");
        });
    });

    //Toggle Optional Inputs Group
    $(".input-toggle > div").hide();
    $(".input-toggle a > span:last-of-type").hide();
    $(".input-toggle a").click(function() {
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("fast");
        var spans = $("span", this);
        spans.not(spans.filter(":visible").hide()).show();
    });

    //Responsive Side/Side System
    $(window).on("ready resize", function() {
        if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
            $(".side-by-side.right-side .gridB").each(function() {
                $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('.gridA'));
            });
        } else {
            $(".side-by-side.right-side .gridB").each(function() {
                $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent().find('.gridA'));
            });
        }
    });

    //Sideshow
    $(function() {
        $('.slideShow .slide:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function() {
            $('.slideShow .slide:first-child').fadeOut().next('.slide').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slideShow');
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: FYI 2.1.0 > 1.11.2 is actually a downgrade. Check the console for error messages which may give you a clue about what has broken within your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ops, i have fixed that in the question. I have tried to find out what is wrong from the consoles, but they don't show anything at all :/

Comment: You ask if window.onload is outdated, but I don't see an onload event anywhere in your code? You are using $(window).on("ready"), which I don't think I've seen before. Usually it would be $(document).ready() or $(window).load() or window.onload.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct @JonathanNicol - it is window.ready - which does not work now, however, if I changed it to windows.load it will work but the function will run at the very last, which create a jump whilst the page is loading as it alters some CSS etc..

Comment: Then you should use $(document).ready() which executes once the DOM has loaded: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/. I don't think you will be able to combine your resize and ready event handlers in the way you've been doing. Instead, have one event handler for ready, and one for resize. If you want them both to do the same thing then have them call a function containing your logic.

Comment: I changed `$(window).on("ready resize", function() {` to `$(document).on("ready resize", function() {` and it worked, however, the re-size function does not work now. I guess because it should be applied to the window and not document. Any ideas?

Comment: That's right - I edited my previous comment about to mention that you will need separate event handlers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72671/discussion-between-leo-and-jonathan-nicol).